# Creating a derived class object inside of base class object

Tags: c++, class, matrix, radix, derived

I'm implementing matrices according to the strategy pattern.
for that I have MyMatrix, which holds a pointer to Matrix, and two subclasses that inherit from Matrix - SparseMatrix & RegMatrix.
when adding two matrices, because I can't know which matrix I'm adding to which matrix, I implemented a base function which uses an inner method of each inheriting class, and when adding - I just add the new elements to the lefthand matrix.

This works fine.

my problem is - I now want to perform matrix multiplication. 
I want to implement this method in the base class - Matrix.
this is what I have until now:

```
Matrix& multiple(Matrix &other)
{
    double result = 0;
    int newMatrixRowSize = getRowSize();
    int newMatrixColSize = other.getColSize();
    double *resultArray = new double[newMatrixRowSize*newMatrixColSize];
    for (int i = 1; i <= getColSize(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= other.getColSize(); j++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= other.getRowSize(); k++)
            {
                Pair firstPair(i,k);
                Pair secondPair(k,j);
                result += getValue(firstPair)*other.getValue(secondPair);
            }
            Pair resultIndex(i,j);
            resultArray[getNumIndex(resultIndex, newMatrixRowSize, newMatrixColSize)] = result;
            result = 0;
        }
    }
    delete [] resultArray;
}
```

only problem is, now I can't just add the new elements to the lefthand matrix, I have to create a new RegMatrix or SparseMatrix, and according to the number of zeros in the matrix - swap to the legit representation of matrix.

so my question is - is it "legal" or good practice to create an instance of the base class' derived class inside the base class? 
I want to avoid using the factory pattern, and more willing to do something polymorphic without knowing the kind of matrix in hand

Comment: " I want to avoid using the factory pattern, and more willing to do something polymorphic without knowing the kind of matrix in hand" You don't have a matrix. You are only going to create one. There is no polymorphic behaviour of a Matrix object at this stage because there is no Matrix object.

Comment: There is no problem whatsoever in creating a Matrix derived object inside a Matrix method. There is no other way to return a Matrix object from it. Your reluctance to use the factory pattern doesn't seem well founded.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a factory if you want to create objects of different types depending on condition. If you don't want `Matrix` to know about its descendants, you have several options. Apart from [implementations using interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), in C++11 you can use `std::function`:

```
class Matrix {
     typedef std::function<Matrix*(const double*, int, int)> Factory;
     Factory factory;
public:
     Matrix(const Factory& f) : factory(f) {}
     Matrix* multiple(Matrix &other) {
         ....
         return factory(resultArray, newMatrixRowSize, newMatrixColSize);
     }
};
```

It gives you the advantage that you can pass any function-like object as a factory:

```
Matrix* matrixFactoryFunc(const double* data, int rowSize, int colSize) {
    return nullptr;
}

class MatrixFactoryCallable {
public:
    Matrix* operator()(const double* data, int rowSize, int colSize) {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

class MatrixFactoryWithMemFun {
public:
    Matrix* createMatrix(const double* data, int rowSize, int colSize) {
    }
};

void testFactory() {
    std::function<Matrix*(const double*, int, int)> factory;

    factory = matrixFactoryFunc;

    factory = MatrixFactoryCallable();

    MatrixFactoryWithMemFun mi;
    factory = std::bind(&MatrixFactoryWithMemFun::createMatrix, &mi, _1, _2, _3);

    Matrix m(factory);
}
```